# How to open a wsdl file in IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, wsdl

I have a file with .wsdl extension. When i try to open the same in IE, It goes to "View Downloads" section and asks whether I want to save or open the file. Even if I select 'open', it doesn't open and the same pop up window persists.

Can anyone tell me what is the workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried opening it via notepad?

Comment: Yes... That works.. But it is well alligned to see it in IE, so that I can get track of all methods/fields

Answer (score 1):

Please take the following steps to change the file association of wsdl Files.

1. Open IE, go to Tools, click Internet Options.
2. Navigate to the Programs tab and click on the "Set Programs" button.
3. Click on the "Associate a file type or protocol with a program".
4. Find the .wsdl, then change the default program of it to internet explorer or notepad.

Comment: can you disable automatic prompting for file download and check: http://hdc.tamu.edu/Systems_Software/Web_Browsers/Windows_Internet_Explorer/Change_IE_Security_Settings_to_Enable_File_Downloads.php

Comment: I don't have an option like that in my IE --> Internet Options :(

Comment: Can you not use firefox?

Comment: Tried opening chrome.. It displays the same as in notepad... Not with the formatting